# Change css prefixes in antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using antd react in my project. I need to change the css prefixes for the components in antd. Its setting the prefixes like eg: ant-tabs in css
i need some thing like custom-tabs
 - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The CSS prefixes are hardcoded into the source of each component of Ant.

From the source for the Popover component ([GitHub](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/popover/index.tsx)):

```
static defaultProps = {
  prefixCls: 'ant-popover',
  placement: 'top' as TooltipPlacement,
  transitionName: 'zoom-big',
  trigger: 'hover' as TooltipTrigger,
  mouseEnterDelay: 0.1,
  mouseLeaveDelay: 0.1,
  overlayStyle: {},
};
```

To change these, you'd have to manually edit each component's source code.

Comment: in our very big project we've made the same thing - a few patches for each of the needed components (awful approach but...)

Answer (score 1):

every antd component have `prefixCls` that allow you to override antd class.

(and lose all the style coming from that component)